# What is the easy way to start Task Manager as an administrator in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, if so I apologize for asking this question.

I need to run the Windows 8 task manager as administrator from a standard user account's login session. Under Windows 7 I used to right-click the task bar or hit Ctrl+Alt+Del and pick "Task Manager", then when the task manager window pops up on the screen I'd click the button in the bottom left corner (can't remember its exact name, something to the effect of "Show processes for all users") and the task manager will start as an admin.

Now I understand all the glitzy improvements in Windows 8's task manager, but where the heck is "Show processes for all users" button?

I also understand that I can create a shortcut to run task manager as admin and place it on my desktop, but I rarely see my desktop. It's covered by 10 windows or so. Is there a simpler method to do this that I'm sure Microsoft thought of in their infinite wisdom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pin the Taskmgr shortcut to the taskbar if you don't want to minimize the 10 open Windows.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I ended up doing. Although I honestly hope that they return this option in Windows 8.1.

Comment: I doubt this. Ask it in the Answers or technet win 8.1 forums, so that MS developers read it. I have no idea if someone reads it here.

Comment: This is still required in Windows 10 to run task-manager as administrator. Right-click the shortcut in taskbar, then right-click again on the task manager menu entry to "run as administrator"

Answer (score 3):

If you're running as an administrator, the Task Manager is already elevated by default in Windows 8. You don't need to do anything special for it to run in UAC elevated mode.

[image: Task Manager screenshot]

If you are running as a standard user, there doesn't seem to be any built-in way to elevate the Task Manager. However, you can create a batch file that launches `RunAs` to launch the Task Manager, save that, and put a shortcut to it. Then, set a keyboard shortcut for the shortcut to the batch file. If you want to make the UI nicer and avoid having to use a specific account for the `RunAs` command line program, you can use the [Elevation VBS tool](http://blogs.technet.com/b/elevationpowertoys/archive/2010/06/20/creating-a-self-elevating-script.aspx?Redirected=true) to launch the Task Manager elevated and show a standard UAC prompt.

[image: Shortcut properties]

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: @MikeF see the screenshot above. I opened that just by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Esc, and it's running elevated.

Comment: That's because your `Nathan` is an admin by default. I hope you don't log in like that for every day use?

Comment: @MikeF if you mean how to elevate it from a non-admin user, you should clarify that in your original question. In Windows 7 and later OSes, there's not much risk in running as an admin by default if you have UAC enabled and are careful with what you do.

Comment: Oh, man, don't start me on that. I've been ripping out tons of malware from people's computers who tell me this :) Also clarified the question.

Comment: @MikeF I rip out people's malware for a living, I think I know how to handle my security settings. But thanks for the concern.

Comment: Well, it's a job security for you, right :)

Comment: @MikeF see edits for an alternate solution based on your modified criteria.

Answer (score 3):

1. Press the "Logo" + "S" keys; or Mouse to one of the right-hand corners of the screen; to reveal the search interface.
2. Search for "task manager".
3. Right-click on one of the results, and choose "Run as Administrator"

The Logo+S key combination works in Windows 8.1 to specifically bring up the "Search Everywhere" charm.

Note too: Ctrl+Shift+Esc brings up Task Manager (as the current user).

Comment: Even quicker than right-clicking, just press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

I usually open an elevated command prompt and just execute w/e utility I need. In this case taskmgr.exe

Comment: Yes, I will have to do it without a faster solution. I'd be better off creating an elevated shortcut on a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't trust Microsoft with anything, I do everything manually myself. I find when I most need Windows, Windows is having a bad day.

I therefore use SuRun (http://sourceforge.net/projects/surun/) for this type of thing. SuRun works a lot like sudo (Super User Do) in Linux. I like the fact that you can configure this service to run certain programs as an administrator automatically and transparently (even when not on an administrator account). So when configured SuRun will intercept a request to start task manager and pipe the request as an Admin, either prompting for a password or using a preconfigured admin account.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler than runas etc.

In the charms bar, use search and search for taskmgr right click and choose run as administrator or highlight in the search results and ctrl-shift-enter.

Comment: Can you go over your answer with a bit more detail to allow other people that don't know what you mean to understand it.